# Send email alert

Tags: javascript

The following code is designed to monitor deadlines in a column and send alerts when there are less than 5 and more than 0 days to finish. The code is working.

```
function sendEmails2016_2() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('2016.2');
   var clientesInfo = sheet.getRange(2, 7, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
   //var clientesInfo2 = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues(); --- tentando pegar o assunto na coluna 3

   var subject = sheet.getName(); //nome da planilha
   var email = "roger@tr.br";
   var assunto = "Prazo Monitoramento COAUD vencendo - Planilha " + subject + " ";
   var msg = " clique aqui para abrir https://agenda.com. O prazo vence em ";

  for (var i = 0; i < clientesInfo.length; i++) {
     if (clientesInfo[i][1] < 5 && clientesInfo[i][1] > 0 ) {
       var dias = clientesInfo[i][1];
       //var assunto2 = clientesInfo2[i][2]; --- tentando pegar o assunto
       MailApp.sendEmail(email, assunto, msg + dias + " dias!");

    } 
  }
 }
```

I want to be able to get beyond the days remaining, other information from other columns, such as the matter of maturity (there is a subject titled column). Only I do not know how to do this.

I tried to create a clienteInfo2 variable to store information of the subject column, 3, and within the IF, I tried to create a assunto2 variable and store the array value of each interaction, to get the value of the subject in each of the lines this column, but it does not work. The code runs normally but returns only "undefinid" rather than the subject. Algume know why?

Comment: Why have you changed the array counter from [1] to [2] in your broken variable `var assunto2 = clientesInfo2[i][2];`

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed "2" for "1" and it worked fine.